# How to load templates in complex AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to load templates in complex AngularJS application (many views)?

Would it be in general beneficial to load all templates as a single file or load them on demand?

Does AngularJS provide a way to bundle all templates in one file? Can $templateCache be applied for this purpose?

Comment: yes regarding $templateCache, can also lazy load them and push them to cache. Choices are flexible. Or just use on demand via ajax. If anugular doesn't find templateUrl in cache will make ajax call for it transparently ( worth keeping in mind when creating templateCache url structure)

Answer (score 2):

It's common to use grunt and html2js to convert all of the HTML template files into the template cache.

ng-boilerplate shows this setup in it's Gruntfile.js. https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate.

It's hugely beneficial to take this approach and reduce the number of http requests your application makes.